# Spring Boot 1.3.3., Spring Security basic custom config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I know this is the n. post about Spring Security, and I did read a lot about it, until I decided to post my question, because - I assume - due to the nature of Spring Boot there must be some kind of problem hidden underneath the hood, that is specific to the constellation of Boot version/security type I'm using.

Let me just into it.

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My basic Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('ROLE_STUDENT')")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                Iterable<Student> studentsWithIds = studentRepository.findAll();

                for (Student student: studentsWithIds) {
                    if (student.getName() == username) {
                        return studentRepository.findOne(student.getId());
                    }
                }
                  throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found.");
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

My Student class implementing UserDetails (with HARD-WIRED credentials for simplicity's sake. Role is ROLE_STUDENT):

```
@Entity
public class Student implements UserDetails {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private Integer facebookId;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private Integer googleId;

    private String name = "";
    private String password = "";


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void initialize(String studentName) {
        this.name = "student1";
        this.password = "password";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Student with name " + name + "id: " + id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_STUDENT"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

That's it. I don't have any other security related configuration nor annotation, and as far as I know I don't have to have anything else.

The problem is that when I start the application I still cannot authenticate myself with "student1"/"password", but only with the default "user"/.

Any idea what is missing please? Thank you!

[Naturally there is a user already in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3qg9.png) 
After debug mode turned in:

> 22:06:54.067 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
>   22:06:54.067 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /students/1 at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
>   22:06:54.067 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /students/1 at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
>   22:06:54.067 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /students/1 at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
>   22:06:54.068 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /students/1; Attributes: [hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')]
>   22:06:54.068 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
>   22:06:54.072 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@272de199, returned: -1
>   22:06:54.072 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
>   22:06:54.073 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
>   org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
>       at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   22:06:54.073 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.
>   22:06:54.073 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
>   22:06:54.073 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@13a7abbc
>   22:06:54.077 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
>   22:06:54.080 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /error
>   22:06:54.083 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
>   22:06:54.083 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
>   22:06:54.084 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
>   22:06:54.084 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
>   22:06:54.104 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
>   22:06:54.104 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'error'
>   22:06:54.107 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'error'
>   22:06:54.107 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@2fb1fefe] based on requested media type 'text/html'
>   22:06:54.107 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@2fb1fefe] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
>   22:06:54.113 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
>   22:06:54.113 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
>   22:06:54.113 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
>   22:06:54.114 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@13a7abbc
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/students/1'; against '/css/**'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/students/1'; against '/js/**'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/students/1'; against '/images/**'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/students/1'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/students/1'; against '/error'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**']
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/students/1' matched by universal pattern '/**'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - matched
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /students/1 at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /students/1 at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /students/1 at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@37ca7e0d
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /students/1 at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/students/1'; against '/logout'
>   22:07:02.728 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /students/1 at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
>   22:07:02.730 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'student1'
>   22:07:02.730 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
>   22:07:02.731 [http-nio-8280-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider - User 'student1' not found

The very end seems to be the most interesting although the rest is pretty ugly too:

> o.s.s.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider - User 'student1'
>   not found

Here is where I called the initialize on Student (it's cheating because it should be called on a POST, but again, I was cheating just to put a Student in the database, and use that for authentication. It would be obviously different later on. *Of course I could only make this GET when I temporarely deactivated the security on the app*):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/students", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Student>> listStudents() {
    LOGGER.info("/students controller method call"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date()));
    Iterable<Student> studentsFound = studentRepository.findAll();

    Student newStudent = new Student();
    newStudent.initialize("student1");
    studentRepository.save(newStudent);

    return new ResponseEntity<Iterable<Student>>(studentsFound, HttpStatus.OK);         
}
```

Do you think the Student instance itself is somehow not correct?

Comment: Where did you call the `initialize` method of `Student`?

Comment: added the initialize part. extended with some explanation (I know it doesn't make sense there, but just wanted to save a Student into the DB, wherever. That part already worked without the auth, so I've put it there. The DB is on Update mode, the record is certainly still in the DB, but I was double checking it too)

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that when I start the application I still cannot
>   authenticate myself with "student1"/"password", but only with the
>   default "user"/.

It means the default user (configured by default `AuthenticationManager`) is still enabled. In order to fix this issue,  just *Inject* the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to the `configure` method:

```
@Override
@Autowired
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { ... }
```

Based on [Spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security):

> To also switch off the authentication manager configuration you can
>   add a bean of type `AuthenticationManager`, or **else configure the global
>   AuthenticationManager by autowiring an AuthenticationManagerBuilder
>   into a method in one of your @Configuration classes**.

So, in order to disable the default `AuthenticationManager`, you should `Autowire` an `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to a configuration method.

I know it's off topic but the following piece of code seems extremely inefficient to me:

```
Iterable<Student> studentsWithIds = studentRepository.findAll();
for (Student student: studentsWithIds) {
    if (student.getName() == username) {
        return studentRepository.findOne(student.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: an explanation of why he needs to inject the AuthenticationManagerBuilder would probably help OP understand why he is having an issue

Comment: @Turtle Updated the answer, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion, but simply adding @Autowired to protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { ... } did not seem to change anything. Something is still off.
(yes, that is probably not the final version how I'm going to get the user from the database, I'm just so desperate at this point, that I don't mind quick and dirty things like that for the time being).
The strange thing is that I don't think the execution even gets to that configure method, because than at least I should see a UsernameNotFoundException shouldn't I?

Comment: `UsernameNotFoundException` will be caught by `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and translated to HTTP responses. So you won't see that exception unless you use `debug` log level.

Comment: I wish debugging would currently work in my eclipse, that would make it a lot easier.... (that is another problem straining my nerves, I suppose I need to do something extra to be able to debug such an application (tomcat?), as currently debugger just simply does not attach when I start the application in debug mode). I try to change to debug level.

Comment: Posted a lot of debug logs, sorry for the format.
For me it seems that the last line explains it: "DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider - User 'student1' not found". The only question what to do with the DaoAuthenticationProvider.